# Execute command up to end

Tags: linux, bash

I need to create bash script to kill all citrix process. and stop killing process when no process found. I tryed this, but is wrong. Can you help me?

```
check=`ps -ef | grep citrix | grep -v grep | wc -l`
while [ $check -gt 1 ]
do
ps -ef | grep citrix | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill "$2}' | bash

done
```

Comment: How is it "wrong"? What does it not do that it should do? Does it do everything it should do, but does it print errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: You're never reassigning `check`, so even if killing the processes is successful, the loop will never exit.

Comment: Beyond that -- code generation is a source of major security errors, and it's completely pointless. Use `pkill` to find matching processes and kill them. (Also, `grep | grep | awk` is silly; awk can do everything grep can: `kill $(ps -ef | awk '/[Cc]itrix/ { print $2 }')` is one approach that's still sloppy -- you _really should_ use `pkill` instead -- but not as bad as the original code)

Comment: The other thing here -- if you can at all avoid it, you shouldn't be killing things by PID at all in the first place. Assuming a well-administered system, Citrix should be running as a systemd service, so you should be able to use `systemctl` to tell systemd itself to stop it. systemd uses cgroups to track processes associated with each service; one of the advantages this gives is that it can identify if the Citrix service starts children that don't have "citrix" anywhere in their names.

Comment: Please show output of `ps -ef | grep citrix` in your question.

Comment: how i can reasing the variable ? And i use name citrix, just for this example.

Comment: Reassigning the variable looks just the same as assigning it in the first place. Copy the `check=...` line from its original place _before_ the loop to also run it _inside_ the loop, ideally right before the `done`.

Comment: BTW, you should also add a short `sleep` in your loop. Give the process some time to finish closing after it gets a SIGTERM before you try to kill it again.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use [`pkill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) to kill a process that matches a string.

Its exit status indicates whether it successfully found processes to kill, so you can use that in the `while` condition.

```
while pkill citrix
do 
    sleep 1
done
```